Customise details in an ASP.NET Core UnprocessableEntityResult
I've got an ASP.NET Core 9 Web API project with a POST action that creates a new resource.
It expects a specific type of object in the request body, and the object's properties have the usual validation attributes, e.g. [Required], [MaxLength] etc
That all works beautifully and if there are any validation problems, the response body looks like e.g.
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "errors": {
    "Surname": [
      "The Surname field is required."
    ],
    "Forename": [
      "The field Forename must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '20'."
    ]
  },
  "traceId": "00-250e7a400ba440a4242639ce55ce4fc9-6ac285dbee25ccb7-00"
}

But at the server side, I've got a bit more validation and there are several situations where the creation can fail, even though the request is structured correctly. The main one is if the client has requested a unique identifier (username) that already exists on the database, but there are a couple of others.
In this situation, I return a http 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
return UnprocessableEntity();

but all the client gets back is something like this
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4918#section-11.2",
  "title": "Unprocessable Entity",
  "status": 422,
  "traceId": "00-51c4a1bfa660009efcaed400a2dbf100-85b6faeb7047cf4c-00"
}

The problem here is that the client doesn't know why the request has failed.
How can I add extra information to the response body? Customising the text in the "title" property would be enough, but if I could manually add extra properties like the "errors" array that ASP.NET uses, that would be ideal.
I notice that the Problem() method takes a "detail" parameter, so if I do
return Problem("My custom message");

then I get
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.6.1",
  "title": "An error occurred while processing your request.",
  "status": 500,
  "detail": "My custom message",
  "traceId": "00-24e490f7b526b65e4e0747dc4c37b99f-5f2ae15f95791e04-00"
}

but the UnprocessableEntity() method doesn't have that option.

You could use UnprocessableEntity with custom error message like below:
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private ProblemDetailsFactory _problemDetailsFactory;
    
    public TestController (ProblemDetailsFactory problemDetailsFactory)
    {
        _problemDetailsFactory = problemDetailsFactory;
    }
    public IActionResult Post(User model)
    {
        if (_dbContext.Users.Any(u => u.Username == model.Username))
        {
            var problemDetails = _problemDetailsFactory.CreateProblemDetails(HttpContext, 422);
            problemDetails.Detail = "The username is already taken.";
            return UnprocessableEntity(problemDetails);
        }
        //do your stuff...
    }
}


Awesome, works perfectly, thanks! I found I can also use the ProblemDetailsFactory to create a ValidationProblemDetails, which gets me the "errors" array in the response.
